# Cycles synchronizing static objects each frame

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to render a scene with a huge mesh (it's a spaceship made with kitbashing, it has millions of polygons, no subdivision modifier is used), the object is completely static and only the camera is moving, but cycles is resynchronizing the mesh each frame which is taking a lot of time.

However, in the viewport, cycles keep the mesh in the ram and I can navigate between frames without having to resync the mesh.

Is there a way to avoid resynchronization on render ?

[image: viewport_rendering]

[image]